# Why not all form controls could be rendered via HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-principles

Does anybody know why could some HTML form controls be rendered using [System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx) (hidden, checkbox, password, textbox) and some couldn't and should be explicitly written in HTML (file, submit)? What is the principle of this separation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.

I would think the input controls (e.g. input, select) are wrapped in Html helpers so they can maintain their own state via TempData without the user having to write a lot of code to achieve that. I would also think link and form controls are wrapped to give an easy and uniform way to specify the controller / action for those controls. Most other controls don't warrant either out-of-the-box state management or need controller / action urls built.

Of course there's nothing to stop you writing your own wrappers for whichever controls you like - e.g. here are a couple I use - here's one for an html label control:

```
public static string Label(this HtmlHelper helper, string fieldName, string labelText)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<label for=\"");
    sb.Append(fieldName);
    sb.Append("\">");
    sb.Append(labelText);
    sb.Append("</label>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And here's one that I use that wraps that label helper and a textbox to produce a uniform text input field complete with label:

```
public static string TextField(this HtmlHelper helper, string labelText, string fieldName, string value)
{
    return string.Concat(
        "<div>",
        helper.Label(fieldName, labelText),
        helper.TextBox(fieldName, value),
        "</div>");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found Phil Haack's answer in thread ["Html.SubmitButton() missing in Preview4?"](http://forums.asp.net/t/1295135.aspx) concerning the problem:

> Yeah, we are trying to keep the
>   helpers somewhat minimalist. Not only
>   that, we've received feedback from
>   some people that many of our helpers
>   are unnecessary. "I know HTML, why do
>   I need a SubmitButton helper?".
>
> We figured that since input buttons
>   generally are not used to render user
>   input, the helper method has marginal
>   value. After all, with the VS HTML
>   editor, you get intellisense when you
>   type . It tells you
>   which attributes are available. Our
>   helper doesn't.
>
> ...
>
> The thing we want to avoid is having a
>   helper for every html element. That
>   would make no sense: Html.Div.
>
> We want to come up with a design
>   rationale for helpers. Maybe we have
>   one for all the common form elements,
>   not just the ones that show user
>   input. That's a possibility in which
>   case we would include SubmitButton.
>
> Right now, our rationale is any common
>   form helper that renders user input,
>   or any helper that renders routing
>   info, has a helper...